# Why compiler assembly C program into this?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, keil, 8051

I don't understand why the C51 compiler (in Keil) convert C source to this assembly language code: (As p is a pointer to unsigned char)

```
;   p++;
            ; SOURCE LINE # 216
    MOV     R3,pDisplay?253
    INC     pDisplay?253+02H
    MOV     A,pDisplay?253+02H
    MOV     R2,pDisplay?253+01H
    JNZ     ?C0090
    INC     pDisplay?253+01H
```

As `R3` and `R2` wasn't used in the next lines of the program. 
Why do compiler make these lines
`MOV  R3,pDisplay?253`,
 `MOV  R2,pDisplay?253+01H`?

Comment: Have you enabled optimization?

Comment: The optimization was set at level 8 by default.

Comment: Please show both a complete C function and a complete assembly dump of that function.  "This assembly corresponds to this C source" annotations in assembly dumps are frequently wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to 1980s "state of the art" code generation for 8-bit target processors.  What the code is doing is "noting the value" of p before incrementing it.  That's necessary when the postincrement operator is used in a surrounding expression; and not optimized away by subsequent passes of the compiler.

Try `p += 1;`, or even `++p;` instead.  Odds are that one or both of those will generate better code because there is no "note the value before" semantics to get in the code generator's way.

[This is how I got into the minority, by the way, using `++i` in `for ()` loops rather than the more common `i++`.]

Comment: I've got it. And I tried the code like `p0 = p++;` and found Keil used a function in the library `?C?CLDPTR` to load R1/R2/R3 data to A and finally passed A to p0.<br/>Thank you.

Comment: @Gamcheong That's an example where the "note the previous value" is important. It's equivalent to `p0 = p1, p1 += 1;` and there's no reason for any compiler to generate better code with the longer explicit version.  If cycles or code bytes matter, avoid `p1++` for just incrementing without using the previous value of `p1`.